# Problem with the Truclient script in the Loadrunner cloud

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am creating a script in LoadRunner desktop version (VuGen > Truclient). The script packs into ZIP and loads into LoadRunner Cloud to perform performance test. I also load needed text files used as attachments to forms. It loads them into Data Files.

My question is: **how to change the path in the script to the file to download, those files in File Data that I also linked to this script used as attachments to the form?**

(In a nutshell: I mean, a desktop version of the path alternative, as you know, starting with C:.........). Or another way that allows me to execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

The file is copied to the script directory during execution and you can retrieve the full path by executing `TC.scriptDir/ + "fileName"`

Comment: Great this method works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted and upvoting it.